# GTK C how to add scrolled window to vbox

Tags: c, ubuntu, gtk, gnome, gtk2

I can't put scrolled window into main_v_box , what is wrong? I just see this little strange orange strip. When I move the cursor on it, horizontal scroll appears but I can't see text. Thanks  in advance. [image]

```c
  //formula_h_box
  formula_h_box = gtk_hbox_new(FALSE, 0);
  gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(main_v_box), formula_h_box, FALSE, FALSE, 0);

  //formula_hscrollbar
  formula_scrolled_window = gtk_scrolled_window_new(NULL, NULL);
  gtk_scrolled_window_set_policy(GTK_SCROLLED_WINDOW(formula_scrolled_window), GTK_POLICY_ALWAYS, GTK_POLICY_ALWAYS);




    GtkWidget *view;
    GtkTextBuffer *buffer;

    view = gtk_text_view_new();

    buffer = gtk_text_view_get_buffer (GTK_TEXT_VIEW (view));

    gtk_text_buffer_set_text (buffer, "HHello, this is some textHello, this is some textHello, this is some t\nextHello, this is some textHello, this is some textHello, this is some textHello, this\n is some textHello, this is some textHello, this is some textHello, this is some textHello, this is some textHello, this is some textHello\n, this is some textHello, this is some textHello, this is some textHello, this is some textHello, this is some textHello, this is some textHell\no, this is some textHello, this is some textHello, this is some textHello, this is some textHello, this is some textHello, this is some textHello, this is som\ne textHello, this is some textHello, this is some textHello, this is some textHello, this is some textHello, this is some textHello, this is some textello, this is some text", -1);





  gtk_scrolled_window_add_with_viewport(GTK_SCROLLED_WINDOW(formula_scrolled_window), view);
  gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(formula_h_box), formula_scrolled_window, TRUE, TRUE, 0);
  //gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(formula_h_box), formula_scrolled_window);
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem, that the scrolled window does not fill the window? If so, is the box the immediate child of the window?

Comment: Yes, I want to see that text below button and entry. I don't know if the box is the immediate child of the window, I have just started learning gtk+. I was adding one box to another with (gtk_box_pack_start) and finally there is something as "gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), main_space_h_30_box);"

Comment: I have test your code a looks good for me, perhaps you should include all the code to help you better, including the creation of the window and the other elements. I think that some of the widget is not expanded, but not clear which one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried once again but with image widget and now it works. Thanks for replies.

```
//formula_h_box
  formula_h_box = gtk_hbox_new(FALSE, 0);
  gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(main_v_box), formula_h_box, FALSE, FALSE, 10);

  //formula_hscrollbar
  formula_scrolled_window = gtk_scrolled_window_new(NULL, NULL);
  gtk_scrolled_window_set_policy(GTK_SCROLLED_WINDOW(formula_scrolled_window), GTK_POLICY_ALWAYS, GTK_POLICY_ALWAYS);

  gtk_widget_set_size_request(formula_scrolled_window, 400, 200);
  gtk_scrolled_window_add_with_viewport(GTK_SCROLLED_WINDOW(formula_scrolled_window), image);
  gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(formula_h_box), formula_scrolled_window, FALSE, FALSE, 0);
```